# How is this possible? Different object when assigning a return value to a variable instead of using it itself

Tags: angular

My angular/typescript code:

```
const reportRequest = this._localStorage.getKey(this._localStorage.budgetReportFilterName);
console.log(reportRequest);
console.log(this._localStorage.getKey(this._localStorage.budgetReportFilterName));
```

local storage is a service, here's the fn I'm using:

```js
public getKey(keyName: string) {
  const savedFilter = localStorage.getItem(keyName);
  if (savedFilter != null) {
    // console.log(JSON.parse(savedFilter));
    return JSON.parse(savedFilter);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Values are different, see arrays in the object in the image that I attached.

That is for the same instance, I'm breaking my head hoping that this is an Angular bug and it's not me.

[image: Console output]

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure something isn't overwriting it with new values?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is not an issue with angular. You must be mutating the local storage value from other places